# Command dig to resolve network issues

Tags: command-line, fonts, download, dig

I am downloading a font resource from an external font loader. However, it is taking a long time to download. I am in contact with a member of the support team who has asked me to provide him with the output of `dig resource.com` to provide him with more information.

Where should I run the command `dig`? I tried the windows command line, but `dig` is not a recognized command. Is there a browser utility to run this command? If this is a linux-only operation, is there a comparable Windows operation? Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`dig` is a Linux command to do DNS lookups.  There are versions of `dig` available for windows, but you can simply use nslookup instead.  Just open a command window (you can do this by clicking start... then type cmd).  Then, in the command window, type `nslookup resource.com`.